# Docusign Developement E-Mails

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the DocuSign API to allow the first person in a chain of people to sign an embedded document. The rest of the people should sign the document via e-mail. Is this possible? Is there a limit of how many e-mails you can send from a developer account? I'm successfully creating and signing the envelope but none of the other e-mail accounts I have listed on the envelope receive a copy.

```
String requestBody = "<envelopeDefinition xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">" +
                    "<accountId>" + accountId + "</accountId>" +
                    "<status>sent</status>" +
                    "<emailSubject>" + emailSubject + "</emailSubject>" +
                    "<emailBlurb>" + emailBlurb + "</emailBlurb>" +
                    "<templateId>81bcad0d-91ed-4616-ae97-f281b2xxxxxx</templateId>" +
                    "<templateRoles>" +
                        "<templateRole>" +
                            "<email>" + emailaddr4[0] + "</email>" +
                            "<name>" + names[0] + "</name>" +
                            "<roleName>Student</roleName>" +
                            "<clientUserId>1</clientUserId>" +
                            "<tabs>" +
                                "<textTabs>" +
                                    "<text>" +
                                        "<tabLabel>sid</tabLabel>" +
                                        "<value>" + student_id + "</value>" +
                                    "</text>" +
                                "</textTabs>" +
                            "</tabs>" +
                        "</templateRole>" +
                        "<templateRole>" +
                            "<email>" + emailaddr4[1] + "</email>" +
                            "<name>" + names[1] + "</name>" + 
                            "<roleName>Advisor</roleName>" + 
                        "</templateRole>" +
                        "<templateRole>" +
                            "<email>" + emailaddr4[2] + "</email>" +    
                            "<name>" + names[2] + "</name>" + 
                            "<roleName>Dept Head of Major</roleName>" +
                        "</templateRole>" +
                        "<templateRole>" +
                            "<email>" + emailaddr4[3] + "</email>" +    
                            "<name>" + names[3] + "</name>" + 
                            "<roleName>Dean of School</roleName>" +
                        "</templateRole>" +
                    "</templateRoles>" +
                "</envelopeDefinition>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you ***do not*** set the **clientUserId** property for a recipient in the "Create/Send Envelope" API request, then DocuSign should send an email to the recipient when it becomes their turn in the envelope routing order.

I'd suggest that you try executing a "Get Recipients" call (`https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/recipients?include_tabs=false&include_extended=false`) for the Envelope and examine the response as a means of troubleshooting:

- Examine recipients and email addresses -- do they match what you expect?
- Is the **clientUserId** property set for any of the recipients?  If that property is set for a recipient, DocuSign will NOT email them when it's their turn to sign.
- What is the value of the top-level **currentRoutingOrder** property in the response?  Only recipients who have a **routingOrder** property value equal to or less than the value of the top-level **currentRoutingOrder** property -- AND who also do not have the **clientUserId** property set -- will have received an Email from DocuSign at the current point in time.

Finally, if those troubleshooting tips don't lead anywhere -- definitely check the "Spam" folder for any user who apparently *should have* received an Email from DocuSign but apparently hasn't (i.e., the email never showed up in the Inbox).  There is no limitation imposed upon Demo accounts regarding Envelope usage or number of recipient emails that you're allowed to send -- if you create the Envelope correctly, DocuSign will send the recipient email(s) at the appropriate times in the routing sequence.